# Why use « ce » in « voir c'est croire »

Tags: infinitif, sujet

On [this page](https://about-france.com/french/infinitive.htm) this sentence is presented:

> **Voir c'est croire.** - Seeing is believing.

It appears to me like there are two subjects in this sentence, *voire* (should probably be *voir*) and *ce*.

Why does this sentence say *voire c'est* instead of *voir est* (ignore the superfulous *e* after *voir* for now)?

Comment: There's no *e* after *voir*, I'm really surprised a page about language would make such a mistake. [*Voire*](https://www.wordreference.com/fren/voire) does exist, but it's an adverb and has a very different meaning.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat L'auteur voulait sûrement écrire *Voire c'est croir !* ;-)

Comment: It was probably the same person that put an *e* on voire that also claimed that present participles are used as nouns in English. They aren't, and can't be as a participle is an adjective by definition. It is a verbal noun (also called a gerund) that looks like a participle. Originally the participle ended in *and* (thus resembling a participle in French!) and the gerund in *ing*. Gradually, [as shown here](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/homes/wojtek/copenhagen.pdf) the *ing* form took over and so the gerund and participle became indistinguishable. But that doesn't make them the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a number of cases, *ce* is  used as **subject** of *être*, preceded by a comma and with the pronominal function of repeating the real subject of the sentence (in these uses it has no English equivalent). Among these cases belongs your case which is that of a **real subject being an infinitive**. *Ce* is obligatory here if the complement is also a positive infinitive (as in your example), but is optional otherwise.

Here is another example:

> [Vouloir, c'est pouvoir](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie8/vouloir). When there is a will there is a way.

Reference: H. Ferrar, A French Reference Grammar, 1988, OUP.

See also:

https://www.bonjourdefrance.com/exercices/contenu/lemploi-de-linfinitif.html:

> B. Quand c’est un nom, l’infinitif s’utilise souvent pour exprimer des
>   maximes, des vérités générales, des proverbes.
>
> Promettre est facile, tenir est difficile.
>
> Donner c’est donner, reprendre c’est voler.